# How to save command output from Gitlab CI in docker container's syslog

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab runners installed in Docker with Docker executors and I would like to save some logs to my docker container. In bash I can do something like this to redirect output to syslog:

```
echo "hi" | logger
```

But I would like to do this straight from my Gitlab CI script. Let's say I want my job to look like this.

```
    image: python:latest
    
    stages:
      - my_stage

    my_job:
      stage: my_stage
      tags:
        - test
      script:
        - echo "Hi - only print"
        - echo "Hi - print and save to syslog" | logger -s
```

I need to save the second output to syslog in docker container but don't know how to do this. I guess my solution doesn't work because I am trying to save it in the container dynamically created by Gitlab Runner. Is there some other way to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount a file (or other descriptor) into your jobs and write to that.

For example, in your runner config:

```ini
    volumes = ["/var/log/ci-job-logs/"]
```

And in your job:

```yaml
- echo "hello logfile" >> "/var/log/ci-job-logs/${CI_JOB_ID}.log"
```

The files are stored on the host, but you could share the mount point `/var/log/ci-job-logs/` (or whatever file/directory you want) with other containers, like a containerized logging daemon, syslog tool, pipe to a command, etc.

Comment: I added directory to config.toml in my docker container with Gitlab runner, but don't understand the last part. The logs are visible from CI, but when I try to list them from the container(with GL runner), they are not present. Does it mean I have to do something more? Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I am a little noob in the topic.

Comment: @Matt it depends somewhat on the details -- you probably just have to add the same volume mount to your runner container (e.g., add the volume in the run options like `-v /var/log/foo:/var/log/foo`) when running your _runner_ container. It may be a bit confusing, but when you specify `volumes =` in the config.toml, those paths actually refer to the HOST path/filesystem (**not** runner container filesystem) assuming typical configurations. This is because the options are passed to the host docker socket and the docker daemon on the host is responsible for mounting the volumes. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing docker run options to `-v "/var/log/ci-job-logs/:/var/log/ci-job-logs/"` helped accessing logs from the container with runner. Additionally I had to change config.toml to `volumes = ["/var/log/ci-job-logs/:/var/log/ci-job-logs/"]` and now it work great.